# Check if the partition for a specific value exists

Tags: postgresql

I have got a partitioned table.

```
create table dwh.message_event (
    date_id int4 null,
    fix_date varchar(32) null,
    some_other_columns text null
)
partition by range (date_id);

create table partitions.message_event_20240201 partition of dwh.message_event  for values from (20240201) to (20240210);
create table partitions.message_event_20240202 partition of dwh.message_event  for values from (20240210) to (20240221);
```

Before the day starts I want to be sure that the partition for the current day was created.

I made a view and it works but it looks a bit convoluted

```
create or replace view dwh.v_partitions as
select partition_name,
       (array_agg(partition_interval))[1]::int as date_from,
       (array_agg(partition_interval))[2]::int as date_to
from (select i.inhrelid::regclass                                                          as partition_name,
             (regexp_matches(pg_get_expr(pt.relpartbound, pt.oid, true), '\d{8}', 'g'))[1] as partition_interval
      from pg_catalog.pg_inherits i
               join pg_class pt on pt.oid = i.inhrelid
      where i.inhparent = 'dwh.message_event'::regclass) x
group by partition_name;
```

Could you suggest some simpler code?

Comment: If you just want to do a test, you can simply try an insert and ROLLBACK the transaction, in case of success your partition exists !

Answer (score 0):

You could `INSERT` a row for the current day. If you get an error with the SQLSTATE `23514`, you know that there is no matching partition. If the statement fails, you simply `ROLLBACK` the transaction.